# LinqToSql query data is not submitted to sql server database using InsertAllOnSubmit & SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a static utility class, which handles everything todo with the database. **My Database is a local instance of SQL server express.** The AddTracks method is supposed to insert a list into a table, using LinqToSql.

This method takes a list of track objects, which are plain old objects, and converts them to TrackTable objects, which are LinqToSql objects, via a query. It then inserts the query on submit and submits the changes.

```
    public static void AddTracks(IEnumerable<Track> trackList)
    {
        LinqToSqlDataContext dbContext = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
        var tracks = from field in trackList
                     select new TrackTable
                     {
                         Track_Id = field.Id,
                         Title = field.Title,
                         Album = field.Album,
                         Artist = field.Artist,
                         Duration = field.Duration,
                         Path = field.Path,
                         Image_Path = field.ImagePath
                     };
        dbContext.TrackTables.InsertAllOnSubmit(tracks);
        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Here are my LinqToSql objects

[image]

The problem is that the data in my table is null.

[image]

Here is my data connection

[image]

**My Database is a local instance of SQL server express.**

Any help is much apprechiated. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're checking the right database file.

Comment: @GertArnold how can I ensure I'm doing so? I only have 1 database file: TrackDB.mdf. I dragged the tables, as seen in the data connections image,  from the data connections onto the linqToSql.dbml. I am checking the table, which I set in linqToSql.

Comment: Ah yes, should be OK. I stopped reading at the word 'local'. Localdb files can show up at confusing locations - but that's not going on here. Maybe an unexpected connection string after all? The best check is to create a *new context instance* in code right after the submitting the changes, and check `dbContext.TrackTables.Count()`. If that count is `0` you have compelling evidence that something is wrong.

Comment: Ok. I just called the insert query and then count after. Count was greater than 0. Hmm... Ok, so then I also called count when fetching the data (which happens on app startup), and to my surprise, count was greater than 0 and the data showed up. I'm so confused right now... When I start the app, the data shows up. Thanks for the help.